# Impact of box_code_size in default config file in Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

I am using [object detction api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in tensorflow. As, all model's parameters are defined in config file, but I didn't found any detailed documentation/tutorial. Yes, object detection api also provides a [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) file for configuring jobs, but this is so high level.

Basically, I am using SSD_mobilenet config file for fine tuning the network. I am just wondering that what will happen if I change the `box_code_size` in the config file.

```
box_predictor {
  convolutional_box_predictor {
    min_depth: 0
    max_depth: 0
    num_layers_before_predictor: 0
    use_dropout: false
    dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
    kernel_size: 1
    box_code_size: 4 #want_to_change_this_line
    apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
```

Let say if I change the `box_code_size` from 4 to 8, so the `detection_boxes` will contain 8 values instead of 4?